# i have requirement like sending three emails through API journey for the where contact data is not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketingcloudapi

I need to send three email as follows:

1. user registered on their website we need to send one email with Activation URL
   2.if user not activating his account and trying to login he cannot and there is a option called resend URL. if user clicks on the resend url we need send another email with activation link.
2. for the above two scenario again we need to send Remainder emails after three days. as below:
   for point 1. Verified _User = false then reminder mail
   for point 2. Verified user = false  the second mail.
   for this am using two Journey_DE and one Main_DE ( which is having updated status of User_verifed)

[image]
in the decision split am checking the contact data of Main_DE. but it is not checking correct path.
in the Main_DE Sendrelation is subkey in attribution group contact key is the Sub_key, actual
primary key in Main_DE is Email.

in Normal sending the this decission split working fine when it comes to API journey it is going by false path.
Plz suggest me any alternate way s for the above requirement

Comment: Maybe this is related to decision split and attribute to attribute comparison. Could there be multiple records in your DE entry used in decision split ? In that case attribute to attribute comparison should help to base the decision on the actual record triggering the injection. See https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_data_relationships.htm&type=5

Comment: What do you mean by 'normal sending'? Do you mean that the entry event is a data extension? Is it Salesforce Data? Campaign Data? What fields are you passing differently when you compare the two?

Comment: Normal sending Means, when i checked with Entry source as Data Extention and test the Journey it is going with Correct Path.

Comment: @FrançoisPerret the screen shot that i have given here  in this there will not be multiple records DE  allows only one record

Comment: Okay, so when you do a decision split you can either do it via Journey Data or Contact Data. Have you checked if you're doing a split based on Journey data? In that case it wouldn't honor those who haven't registered, because you're looking at the old data.